# Designing a user session API for both mobile and web clients

Tags: web-application, session-management, jwt, mobile-app

I'm currently working on a project. The apis on the backend will support both mobile and web clients. I'm attempting to design a user management flow for both clients and a bit confused about how to go about this. I came across a few ways to address this but i'm not sure if

1. Have separate APIs for both the client and mobile. This seems expensive, time consuming and redundant.
2. Use the same APIs for both mobile and web-app. Token based authentication to ensure session management. Maintain an auth session table per user and device. Whenever a resource is requested ensure the user is authorized and also token is valid. When a user logouts, revoke the token. Also when a user changes password invalidate all tokens on every device.

I'm leaning towards the second approach and would appreciate some input

**Side Note:** I heard of BFF (Backend for frontend) but that sounds a lot like option 1.

Comment: I consider this question as a duplicate of [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240838/secure-rest-api-for-mobile-and-web-application-usage). Furthermore, this is [a cross post of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993883/designing-a-user-session-api-for-both-mobile-and-web-clients). I suggest to close it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Secure REST API for mobile and web application usage](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240838/secure-rest-api-for-mobile-and-web-application-usage)

Comment: @mentallurg thanks for the reference. I also posed a comment on the link